# Store all possible routes between two nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, graph

I have two master tables named `Node` & `Edge` and two cache table `Route` & `RouteNodes`.
The schema look like as this:

[image: Schema]

I have to write a procedure which execute when a node and edge inserted then every possible route with existing nodes will store in `Route` and `RouteNode`.

I tried many solutions and one of them is this query:

```
;WITH children AS
    (

       SELECT 
         FromNode,
        CAST(ISNULL(convert(varchar,FromNode) + '->' ,'')  + convert(varchar,ToNode) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS Path
       FROM Edge 
       WHERE FromNode =  1 
     UNION ALL
       SELECT 
         t.FromNode,
         list= CAST(ISNULL(convert(varchar,t.FromNode)  + '->' ,'')  + d.Path AS VARCHAR(4000))
       FROM Edge t
       INNER JOIN children  AS d
            ON (t.ToNode = d.FromNode)
     )

    SELECT * 
    from children
```

But it gives only adjacent nodes.
My data and result are:

[image][image]

I expect result something like:

```
1->3
1->3->2
1->3->2->5
1->3->2->5->6
.........
1->4
1->6
1->6->7
```

and so on.
If it is not possible/astronomical then I want to input two nodes and then store all possible routes.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Note: Don't use `varchar` without specifying a length (`varchar(4000)`). On a `cast/convert`, It will default to `varchar(30)` whereas it defaults to a larger value on table creation. And if you declare a variable it defaults to `varchar(1)`. You are very likely to end up truncating your data, and it can be a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is this a Traveling Salesman Problem?  If so, the permutations can easily become astronomical.   10 nodes 3.6MM ...   25 nodes 1.5E+25

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? cffiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk work great for that.